# SQL counts of tests given in year

Tags: sql, database, count, sum

I'm trying to make a sum of tests given in a year from a specific table. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT TO_CHAR(test_date, 'YYYY') AS Year, SUM(yearCount) 
FROM(
            SELECT COUNT(test_date) AS yearCount
            FROM     test_record
), test_record
GROUP BY test_record.test_date
ORDER BY Year ASC;
```

Which gives me the output:

```
YEAR SUM(YEARCOUNT)
---- --------------
1958         12
1991         12
1996         12
1998         12
2000         12
2001         12
2010         12
2012         12
2013         12
```

Now, I understand my problem lies here: `SELECT COUNT(test_date) AS yearCount` , because I have 12 entries in the table so it's obviously giving the count of the number of entries in the table. I need the count of tests given in each year, i.e. the output should look like this:

```
YEAR SUM(YEARCOUNT)
---- --------------
1958         1
1991         1
1996         1
1998         1
2000         1
2001         1
2010         1
2012         1
2013         4
```

So basically my question boils down to: How do I count by year in a date column?
(I'm using ORACLE 7 I believe)

EDIT: Thanks to the below help I was able to get my desired output, but they were both a little "wrong", so I didn't accept them (sorry if that's a Faux pas). Here is my script:

```
SELECT      TO_CHAR(test_date,    'YYYY') AS Year, COUNT(test_date)
FROM        test_record
GROUP BY    TO_CHAR(test_date, 'YYYY')
ORDER BY    Year ASC;
```

Comment: It's unclear what **test_record** contains. Post original data of **test_record** better on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Thanks for showing me this SQLFiddle. My question is answered though.

Answer (score 1):

You want to group by year and not test date.

```
Select count(*), to_date('YYYY',test_data) as year
From test_record
Group by to_date('YYYY',test_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do group by alone , no need for subquery

```
  SELECT  TO_CHAR(test_date,    'YYYY') AS Year, COUNT(test_date)
  GROUP BY TO_CHAR(test_date, 'YYYY')
 ORDER BY Year ASC;
```